# Command not found, when it's in a directory on the path

Tags: python, path

I have the following environment variable set (trying for a 12-factor app approach):

- `PATH="/home/hope/env/bin:$PATH"`

`/home/hope/env/bin` is the bin directory of a virtualenv, it has `gunicorn` and `python` in it, among other things. But running commands under this directory results in some funny behavior, namely:

- `python` works, and `sys.executable` returns "/home/hope/env/bin/python" (`which python` says this too.)
- `gunicorn` doesn't work, despite `which gunicorn` returning "/home/hope/env/bin/gunicorn".

Obviously to serve pages from this Django app, I need to be able to find gunicorn. I feel like I'm missing something basic, any ideas?

Edit: duh, here's supervisor's output: `BACKOFF    can't find command 'gunicorn'`. Both `python` and `gunicorn` are 755 to the same user/group.

Comment: What is the error exactly when you try to run gunicorn? Does the same shell session find that python binary and fail to find gunicorn? What are the permissions on the gunicorn binary?

Comment: Hah! classic mistake. I've added what you asked for, but yes: it's the same.

Comment: Oh, and the shell session fails in the same way: `gunicorn: command not found`

Comment: What does the shebang (`#!`) line in gunicorn look like?

Comment: `#!/home/hope/env/bin/python`

Comment: What happens if you run `/home/hope/env/bin/gunicorn` rather than just `gunicorn`?

Comment: It works then, but I'm afraid the fact that it doesn't work means I've gotten something major wrong in this setup.

Comment: You said `which gunicorn` from a shell finds it? What about `type -ap gunicorn`? What about both of those commands for python? Run those all in the same shell session please.

Comment: here's the funny thing, when I run this as a session (`sudo -u hope PATH="/home/hope/env/bin:$PATH" /bin/bash`) it works, finds gunicorn just fine. But when I run `sudo -u hope ... gunicorn` it fails. wat.

Comment: Your shell is what uses PATH. So `sudo -u hope PATH="/home/hope/env/bin:$PATH" /bin/bash` runs your shell with a modified $PATH whereas `sudo -u hope ... gunicorn` attempts to run gunicorn with a modified $PATH (but notably does not use that path to find gunicorn).

Comment: so... if that's the case I apparently misunderstood how to change environment variables in sudo (and gunicorn?). Any hints on how to do it properly?